# How to get the length of material UI input filed in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, validation, input, formik

I am trying to enable the button when the material input text length is more than 0.

This is a material input field component.

```
const MaterialInput = ({
    name,
    id = name,
    select,
    options = [],
    type,
    label,
    shrink,
    formik,
    disabled,
    handleClick,
}) => {
    return (
        <TextField
            type={type}
            name={name}
            label={label}
            select={select}
            autoComplete='off'
            variant='outlined'
            disabled={disabled}
            className='material-input'
            value={get(formik.values, name, '')}
            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            helperText={get(formik.touched, name) && get(formik.errors, name)}
            error={get(formik.touched, name) && Boolean(get(formik.errors, name))}
            InputLabelProps={{ shrink }}
        >
            {options.map((item) => (
                <MenuItem
                    onClick={handleClick}
                    className='text-capitalize'
                    value={item.value}
                    key={item.value}
                    disabled={item.disabled || false}
                >
                    {item.label}
                </MenuItem>
            ))}
        </TextField>
    );
};
```

This is how I am using it in other components.

aComponent.js

```
                <MaterialInput name={inputName} label={label} formik={typeofForm} />
```

How to Enable button when the length of text field is more than 0.

Comment: where is your `useState()` ? you also need to include that in your code, so that we could help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many other ways to achieve it.

For suppose you material input name is mobileNumber and formik submit logic in component.js you can write below snippet in ur aComponent.js

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (formik.values.mobileNumber.length === 0) {
            // do your disable logic here
        } else {
             // do your logic
        }
    }, [formik.values.mobileNumber]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check your validation on textField onchange, in this case, that you use formik for your form, Formik main component has a a callback function **validate**, you can use this function to handle your validation,

example

```
<Formik
 validate={(values) => { // here check your validations and you have access to the values }}
 validateOnChange
 validateOnBlur
/>
```

Comment: This will work upon clicking submit button. Before submitting I need to check

Comment: You can add validateOnChange, validateOnBlur

Answer (score 0):

you can use what you pass to value prop in TextField and get its length

```
const getInputLength = (formik, name) => {
    const value = get(formik.values, name, '');
    return value.length;
}
```